# Set breadcrumbs asynchronously with angular-breadcrumb

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ncybreadcrumb

I am trying to create dynamic breadcrumbs using [angular-breadcrumb](https://github.com/ncuillery/angular-breadcrumb) and ui-router. In particular, I want to bind the parent breadcrumb link for my state to a model variable, set asynchronously by the controller. The API reference for angular-breadcrumb [gives the following example](https://github.com/ncuillery/angular-breadcrumb/wiki/API-Reference#state-options) of overriding the parent state:

```
$stateProvider.state('product.detail', {
  url: '/{productId}',
  views: [...],
  ncyBreadcrumb: {
    parent: 'category.list({cat: "product"})'
  }
})
```

I then try to replace the hardcoded "product" in this example with something asynchronously set in the child controller (after some service promises resolve), along the lines of:

```
$stateProvider.state('product.detail', {
  url: '/product/:id',
  controller: 'ProductController',
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  ncyBreadcrumb: {
    label: 'Product', 
    parent: 'category.list({cat: vm.category})'
  }
})

...

ProductController.$inject = ['DataLookupService'];
function ProductController(DataLookupService) {
  var vm = this;
  DataLookupService.get(...).$promise.then(function(data) {
    vm.category = data.some_category_id;
  });
  ...
}
```

However, this only sets ncyBreadcrumb.parent once, based on whatever the value of vm.category happens to be at the moment (typically undefined), and does not create a binding to update ncyBreadcrumb.parent as vm.category changes asynchronously.

Can folks think of a way to achieve this, that is, asynchronously set the parent?